# Windows System Assessment Tool has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows-experience-index, winsat

I have Windows 7 SP1 with all the latest updates.

When I try to refresh the "Windows Experience Index", I get an error:

> "Windows System Assessment Tool has stopped working"

The crash is on file winsat.exe.
I try several solutions found on web , like:

1. From Command Prompt, run the "WinSAT formal"
2. Delete the .xml files from `C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore`, and try again to run the WEI.

I'm still getting the above error, and the WEI doesn't finish the process.

The WinSAT.log contains these :

```
070964 (3260) - winsat\logging.cpp:0815: --- START 2015\10\6 4:42:58 AM ---
070996 (3260) - winsat\main.cpp:4301: Command Line = "C:\Windows\system32\winsat.exe" formal -cancelevent bfc3bd0b-e950-416e-82e8-8d3fcb094ad2
071058 (3260) - winsat\processwinsaterror.cpp:0095: ERROR: tried to read resource strings, unknown exception occured
072821 (3260) - winsat\main.cpp:4474: > IsFormal=TRUE  IsMoobe=FALSE.
072883 (3260) - winsat\main.cpp:4585: Watch dog system enabled
072883 (3260) - winsat\main.cpp:4600: Main watch dog timer set to 600.0 seconds

240709 (1716) - winsat\logging.cpp:0815: --- START 2015\10\6 4:45:47 AM ---
240725 (1716) - winsat\main.cpp:4301: Command Line = "C:\Windows\system32\winsat.exe" formal -cancelevent b8d1c2f1-ccf4-4e01-af6e-09048c2a68fe
240725 (1716) - winsat\processwinsaterror.cpp:0095: ERROR: tried to read resource strings, unknown exception occured
241115 (1716) - winsat\main.cpp:4474: > IsFormal=TRUE  IsMoobe=FALSE.
241161 (1716) - winsat\main.cpp:4585: Watch dog system enabled
241161 (1716) - winsat\main.cpp:4600: Main watch dog timer set to 600.0 seconds

067751 (3300) - winsat\logging.cpp:0815: --- START 2015\10\6 17:13:40 PM ---
067813 (3300) - winsat\main.cpp:4301: Command Line = "C:\Windows\system32\winsat.exe" formal -cancelevent 102c93d2-7f9f-430a-bd2e-2aeb8ed51728
067985 (3300) - winsat\processwinsaterror.cpp:0095: ERROR: tried to read resource strings, unknown exception occured
071916 (3300) - winsat\main.cpp:4474: > IsFormal=TRUE  IsMoobe=FALSE.
071978 (3300) - winsat\main.cpp:4585: Watch dog system enabled
071994 (3300) - winsat\main.cpp:4600: Main watch dog timer set to 600.0 seconds
```

What can I do?

Comment: capture a crash dump of winsat crash: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57 . Alos share the file **Winsat.log** from **C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT**

Comment: also create and share the dump. Maybe this helps